# Сравнение содержимого двух MySQL баз данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ubuntu

Есть 2 базы данных по 150 ГБ в развёрнутом виде каждая, в сущности это одна база, но дампы с разницей в несколько месяцев. Развёрнуты они временно на виртуальной машине под Ubuntu. Необходимо их сравнить по содержимому и добавить в более старую базу данных записи из новой. Не нашел никаких инструментов хороших, чтобы проделать такое, руками делать это не реально. Из того, что уже попробовал - Novicat, но он при попытке сравнить базы данных безнадёжно зависает и процесс умирает. За любую помощь буду крайне признателен, ибо с таким ещё не сталкивался.

Comment: Я когда-то давно пробовал инструменты dbForge (правда, для Sql Server). Для MySql тоже [есть](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/). Но я не знаю, как оно на больших объёмах данных.

Comment: *Необходимо их сравнить по содержимому и добавить в более старую базу данных записи из новой.* А что насчёт записей, которые есть в старой, но отсутствуют в новой? оставлять? А если они конфликтуют с новой записью по неключевому уникальному индексу? PS. Если надо "и добавить" - то нафига сравнивать? просто INSERT IGNORE - оно в процессе добавления само сравнится...

Comment: Если есть в новой - надо добавить, если конфликт - данные из новой заменяют старые. А как INSERT IGNORE применить к целой базе данных?

Comment: dbForge попробую